# Install external library in C++ Dev-Cpp

Tags: c++

I am trying to install the FreeImage library in C++ using Dev-Cpp on Windows 10, i put the .h files in the corresponding folder and i added the directories in Dev-cpp, the .DLL file i put it in the folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin` that it's where i have installed Dev-Cpp,also a .lib file i put it in the next folder: `C:\Program Files(x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib` that also it's where i have installed Dev-Cpp, i added -l FreeImage to the linker too.

when i compile the code the .h files are found correctly, but Dev-Cpp gives me errors of type `Undefined reference to`,i understand this is because C++ can't found where it's the functions defined.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <FreeImagePlus.h>

int main(){
    fipImage img;
    img.load("Goten.jpg");


    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjljTTu.o    Aburrido2.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8fipImageC1E15FREE_IMAGE_TYPEjjj'
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjljTTu.o    Aburrido2.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8fipImage4loadEPKci'
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjljTTu.o    Aburrido2.cpp:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8fipImageD1Ev'
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjljTTu.o    Aburrido2.cpp:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8fipImageD1Ev'
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Programacion\collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

Linker:

```
-static-libgcc  -lFreeImage
```

**What i need to do?**  - Sorry for my english.

Comment: Recommendation: Don't move the libraries from wherever they've been installed. Instead tell Code::Blocks where to find them. In the project build options you should find a "Search Directories" tab. Add the location of the libraries.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with the full error message and your full compiler command line

Comment: Done @AlanBirtles

Comment: Are there any messages further up about the library not being found or being ignored? Is the library built for your compiler?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just realized that I have MinGW GCC version 4.9.2 and FreeImage requires 4.4.0